# sub-frame-error-detailswhy I can't see some frames?

Tags: html, html5-video

what is #sub-frame-error-details ....
I can't see some frames of the link https://www.rhino3d.com/6/new/refinements#got-an-edge

Answer (score 0):

It's if they set an HTTP-Header Option named `X-Frame-Options` at their Server-Config.

This way they can decide if (or if not) a browser should be allowed to render a page in a , ,  or . This is used to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

You can read more about this on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options